# Bridge errors from non-Java ActiveMQ consumers in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I have a system where Apache Camel is connected to ActiveMQ and we have a variety of clients processing messages, some of which are using Python via STOMP.

So our setup looks like:

```
Apache Camel <==>  ActiveMQ <==> STOMP client
```

We use the request-reply (InOut) type exchange pattern with these which works quite well. However, the right way to handle errors isn't clear. Ideally, when one of these services fail, I'd like to be able to trigger appropriate error handling in Camel so that we can have a uniform policy for things like retries, fallbacks or alerting for failed processes. With JMS consumers it looks like there is some support to bridge errors in the form of properties like "transferException" etc. However these are only available if the client on the other end is using JMS/Java as they work by serializing the message etc. With generic (eg: STOMP protocol) clients connected to ActiveMQ, I can't see a way to (a) signal that there was an error, and (b) supply details of the error (stack trace, error reason, etc) such that they propagate back to the camel routing / exception handling layer. At the moment, if I want that it looks like I have to implement it manually using interceptors or other means.

Is there a best practice or pattern I can use here?

Ideally there would be a message header / property that could be set such that Camel would interpret the JMS reply as a failure on the other end. However I cannot find such a header in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways:

1. Define on ActiveMQ level some policy to put failed JMS messages in a dead-letter-queue (DLQ). Then you can configure on Camel-level a route consuming that DLQ and reacting appropriately (logging, alert, etc...) upon each failed message. But I'm afraid that you will not be able to get much context (like the error stack trace)
2. Play still on the ActiveMQ level with [advisory messages](https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message). This will allow you to "*to watch the system using regular JMS messages*" (for instance on msg delivery, msg consumption) and setup more or less interceptor-like logic. Not sure that there is a event for failure but it's worth checking...

Comment: Thanks - both good suggestions. I will try these out and check back in a day or two to see if anybody else manages to suggest something more direct!